# Get a specific text value of an element when there is multiple elements with the same class names and attribute names

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return, getelementsbyclassname

```
<div class="my-attributes">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Condition</strong></div>
                    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="condition">New</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Color</strong></div>
                    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="color">Black</div>
                </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="SameClass"><strong>Availability</strong></div>
                <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="avail">In Stock</div>
            </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                    **<div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="qty"> 5 </div>**
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Price</strong></div>
                    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="price">250</div>
            </div>
```

I have multiple divs that has the same class and 'itemprop' attribute and I need to be able to create a function that will return the Quantity (which in the example above is '5')

the catch here is that the structure you see above changes in other pages. In the example above, the Condition and the Color shows but on other pages those do not appear which means the structure changes except the class name and the attribute value of the 'itemprop'. See below:

```
<div class="my-attributes">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="SameClass"><strong>Availability</strong></div>
                <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="avail">In Stock</div>
            </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                    **<div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="qty"> 5 </div>**
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Price</strong></div>
                    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="price">250</div>
            </div>
```

How do I get the Quantity into a JavaScript function and return the value of 5? Without having to edit the code of the site itself?

I have been playing with this but I am sure this is completely and utterly incorrect.

```
function () {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SameClass").getAttribute("itemprop"); 
  if (x = 'price')
  {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("SameClass").getAttribute("itemprop").innerText;
  return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` will return an array. So, when you want to examine the elements in it you will need to either step through them with `.each()` or address a single element by using the `[n]` notation behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes don't change, you can select all the relevant elements then get the value from the one you need.

```js
function getQty() {
  var qty;
  document.querySelectorAll("div.SameClass-value").forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute("itemprop") === "qty") {
      qty = element.innerText;
    }
  });
  return qty;
}

console.log(getQty());
```

```html
<div class="my-attributes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Condition</strong></div>
    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="condition">New</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Color</strong></div>
    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="color">Black</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Availability</strong></div>
    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="avail">In Stock</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="qty"> 5 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="SameClass"><strong>Price</strong></div>
    <div class="SameClass-value" itemprop="price">250</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That one worked. You are awesome. Do you know any online courses I can take up for this? I am surely looking for something to study to get my skills polished. Thanks!

Comment: @cars10m - Ha ha :)

Comment: @datalayernoob - Unfortunately I have no recommendations. But you can definitely learn a lot here. Here and Google is where I learned.

Answer (score 2):

The following might work for you:

```
function getQty() { 
  var arr=document.getElementsByClassName("SameClass-value");
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   if (arr[i].getAttribute("itemprop") == 'qty') return arr[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Or, even shorter, you can do

```
function getQty() { 
  return document.getElementsByClassName("SameClass-value")
  .find(d=>d.getAttribute("itemprop") == 'qty').innerHTML;
}
```

Sorry for the repeated edits. It's been a long day for me today and I was trying to quickly put something together on my little smartphone.

Comment: "How do I get the Quantity"

Comment: Substitute 'qty' for 'price' in the above functions.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck - Yeah, but not what they asked for. Besides that, the `SameClass` doesn't contain the value.

Comment: Of course, yes! I just replaced `price` by `qty` and `sameClass` by `sameClass-value`.

Comment: Both this and the above worked Thank you all! I am a noob and I thank you all. Do you have any links or online courses that you know I can look into studying to learn much more about JavaScript coding like this? Thanks again!!

Comment: There is so much stuff out there. Difficult to say which will be your style. Just have a pick and start experimenting. I prefer the following pages https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Javascript